# python: simplify return statement (trigraph?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following simple code:

```
import re

def my_match(s):
    if re.match("^[a-zA-Z]+", s):
         return True
    else:
         return False
```

Is there a way to collapse this in a single `return` statement? In `C` we could do for example:

```
return match("^[a-zA-Z]+", s) ? true : false;
```

Is there something similar in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: Trigraphs are something completely different. What you mean is a ternary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python also supports this, although the syntaxes is a little different than most languages.

```
import re

def my_match(s):
    return True if re.match("^[a-zA-Z]+", s) else False
```

In general, the Python syntax is `val_when_true if cond else val_when_false`, compared to the `cond ? val_when_true : val_when_false` you see in other languages.

In your particular case though, you can just write:

```
import re

def my_match(s):
    return bool(re.match("^[a-zA-Z]+", s))
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generell solution would be to use the following code line. It excludes a fit with length 0 as it specificly checks for the None statement. In this case an empty string is impossible but it is more explicit.

```py
return re.match("^[a-zA-Z]+", s) is not None
```

Comment: Thanks, I remember I saw this syntax elsewhere, but forgot.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers show the ternary equivalent in Python.  But since Python also assigns `truthiness` to values and expressions, you could simply use:

```
my_match = lambda s : bool(re.match("^[a-zA-Z]+", s))
```

Comment: I think you mean "ternary" rather than "trigraph"

Comment: oops.  not very awake.  thanks. @CoffeeTableEspresso

Answer (score 0):

`re.match()` returns a value that can be evaluated for *truthiness*.  So if you don't need to return the *exact* values `True` and `False`, you can just directly return the result of the `match()` function:

```
def my_match(s):
    return re.match("^[a-zA-Z]+", s)
```

And then the caller can say:

```
if my_match(x):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Although in this specific case, `my_match()` becomes a mostly useless wrapper function, and you could just call `re.match(...)` directly.

```
if re.match(...):
   ...
else:
   ...
```